# Android parse this JSON - how?

Tags: android, json

my json:

```
[
    {
        "all": {
            "dates": [
                {
                    "date": "2011-01-18",
                    "name": "asd"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2011-02-19",
                    "name": "ddd"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2011-11-21",
                    "name": "eee"
                }
            ],
            "dep": [
                {
                    "code": "BBB",
                    "name": "BUD"
                }
            ],
            "citys": [
                {
                    "id": "2163",
                    "name": "ASD"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2369",
                    "name": "EFG"
                },

...
```

my code

```
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(s); //json string
                for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                    String settings         = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("all");
                    JSONArray jsonarray     = new JSONArray(settings);

                    for (int j=0; j<jsonarray.length();j++){

                        String dates            = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j).getString("dates");
                        JSONArray jsonarray2    = new JSONArray(dates);

                        for (int k=0; k<jsonarray2.length();k++){
                            String date         =    jsonarray2.getJSONObject(k).getString("date");


                            Log.e("date", date);
                        }
..
```

.

> 07-19 09:52:31.356: ERROR/ex(19038): org.json.JSONException: Value
>   {"citys":[{"id":"2163","...

How can I parse this file correctly?

Thanks, Leslie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
json.getJSONObject(i).getString("all");
JSONArray jsonarray     = new JSONArray(settings);
```

'all' is a JSONObject, not a JSONArray, so get JSONObject and get JSONArrays dates,dep,citys.

Can directly get `json.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("all");` or getJSONObject from String, 
`JSONObject jsonobj     = new JSONObject(settings);`

Comment: realized and was about to edit :)

Comment: can you post the all code? thanks

Comment: sorry too busy for that, hope u found the error and can do it yourself